# Spring boot built .jar Mojarra not Initializing

Tags: spring, maven, jsf, spring-boot

When running a `mvn clean package` and deploying through my terminal with `java -jar application.jar` my application will not run, throwing a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.` but will run when running the application directly (`Application.java -> Run main()`)

I might have found the reason, now I need to learn how to fix it. The relevant line is:

`INFO 7556 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.e.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config     : Initializing Mojarra 2.2.11 ( 20150505-0732 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.11@14688) for context ''`

This line shows itself when running the Application.java, but doesn't appear in the `java -jar application.jar` output. Which I believe leads me to the ApplicationFactory error, which is actually correct in this instance, it really cannot find an ApplicationFactory at all!

So I had been googling how to resolve `java.lang.IllegalStateException [...] javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.` which is what the application throws, and learned that it could be thrown due to a polluted jsf-impl/jsf-api, or a misconfigured javax faces.

However, with this new discovery I found out that since Mojarra 2.2.11 isn't getting added to the spring-boot, the error becomes a matter of course.

This is [a question I still haven't solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232724/spring-boot-runs-in-intellij-idea-mvn-packaged-jar-throws-java-lang-illegalsta), on the same issue, however this discovery completely changes the scope of the error itself, and the approach as to how to fix it.

Any idea of how I can make my `mvn clean package` properly add jsf-impl and jsf-api so that Mojarra will run in my Spring boot project? Below is my pom.xml

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>iSAP</groupId>
    <artifactId>CFDI</artifactId>
    <version>0.3</version>
    <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>recepcion-cfdi</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <io.spring.platform-version>1.1.2.RELEASE</io.spring.platform-version>
        <!-- AssertJ is not a part of Spring IO platform, so the version must be provided explicitly -->
        <assertj-core-version>1.5.0</assertj-core-version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.21</tomcat.version>
        <start-class>com.isap.config.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${io.spring.platform-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- PRIMEFACES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /PRIMEFACES -->

        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Tomcat -->

        <!-- Microsoft JDBC -->
        <!-- NOTE: This is saved locally in the /lib folder.
             Microsoft doesn't allow maven to have it in a public repository. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <!-- These two lines are edited out when the local repo is installed, if you don't
             have JDBC installed locally you should unedit these two lines -->
            <!--<scope>system</scope>-->
            <!--<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/sqljdbc41.jar</systemPath>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- /Microsoft JDBC -->

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Hibernate -->

        <!-- Prettyfaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ocpsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettyfaces-jsf2</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Prettyfaces -->

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
            <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
            <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Core -->

        <!-- Imported for CFDI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mx.bigdata.cfdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>cfdi-base</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Imported for CFDI -->

        <!-- Imported for validacionCFDI -->
        <!-- JDOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /JDOM -->

        <!-- Xerces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Xerces -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Imported for validacionCFDI -->



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Hreqw6HZ) of the Application.java being run, the line where Mojarra appears is line 29. And here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yg1mbWf7) with the Spring-boot not showing the Mojarra startup on lines 44-45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to fix it!

I found [this github issue.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1428) Which detailed why it was running in IntelliJ and not in Spring Boot.

Following intructions inside, including some modifications to my Application.java, and a few others in there and I got stuff working.

Best of luck if you have this issue, it's a complicated one.